# Python missing module docstring with squiggy lines in code

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and I was able to setup my environment today, wrote my first code. I have been seeing a lot of squiggy lines with "Missing module docstring". I am using visual studio code for my development. How can I turn these messages off? Please see attached screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pylint is a Python static code analysis tool which looks for programming errors, helps enforce a coding standard, sniffs for code smells and offers simple refactoring suggestions.

if you want to disable it, go to `settings.json` hit `F1` and choose `Preferences: open settings (JSON)` and edit this line as `"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false` and save it.